# Echo a command to a file with linebreaks

Tags: bash, file, shell, echo

I want to echo ettercap like so:

```
sudo echo $(ettercap -i eth0 -Tq) > /file
```

When I "cat" the file it should give me something like this:

```
ettercap NG-0.7.4.2 copyright 2001-2005 ALoR & NaGA

Listening on eth0... (Ethernet)

...
```

But instead it gives me this:

```
ettercap NG-0.7.4.2 copyright 2001-2005 ALoR & NaGA Listening on eth0... (Ethernet) ...
```

How do I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not `sudo ettercap -i eth0 -Tq > /file`?

Comment: I feel so dumb right now '-' thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. `$(command)` does a substitution, and naturally, it has to be rid of line breaks, as it is provided as a part of a parameter list, which is normally done without line breaks within.

Comment: @TNW - add your comment as an answer and I'll upvote

Comment: @TNW Me too :), I didn't read it before answering the question. The answer was so clear that I just opened the textbox....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

```
sudo ettercap -i eth0 -Tq > /file
```

That's it!

---

If you need this output in a variable before saving it to a file, use the `$()` operator:

```
output=$(ettercap -i eth0 -Tq)
echo "$output" > /file
```

Note that it's the double quotes around "$output" that are crucial to maintaining the whitespace

Comment: Backtics are [deprecated](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#BashFAQ.2BAC8-082.Why_is_.24.28....29_preferred_over_.60....60_.28backticks.29.3F) Use `$(...)`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Check my update. Didn't know before. Really liked them.

Comment: Note that it's the double quotes that are crucial to maintaining the whitespace